# Why does my query in oracle take longer when I use temporary tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g, database-administration

I am facing a peculiar issue when using an inner query in `ORACLE DB`. I am fetching data from a table which is having huge number of records. 
The query I am using contains an inner query.

- When I provide the values directly in the inner query it is much
  faster.
- But when I use exactly the same values from another (temporary) table
  by either inner query or JOIN, it takes too longer.

Below is the query:

### Faster performance

```
SELECT   assembly_item_id menuItemId,
         location_id restId,
         bill_sequence_id,
         bill_config_id
  FROM   zil_ibat_resolve_bmi_ai_max_v
 WHERE   assembly_item_id = 8321
         AND location_id IN (82, 85, 116, .........)
```

---

### Low in performance when used select query in inner section

**Without JOIN**

```
SELECT   assembly_item_id menuItemId,
         location_id restId,
         bill_sequence_id,
         bill_config_id
  FROM   zil_ibat_resolve_bmi_ai_max_v
 WHERE   assembly_item_id = 8321
         AND location_id IN (SELECT   temp_id FROM global_temp_ids)
```

---

**With JOIN**

```
SELECT   assembly_item_id menuItemId, location_id restId, bill_sequence_id, bill_config_id 
FROM   zil_ibat_resolve_bmi_ai_max_v t1
join global_temp_ids t2
on t1.location_id = t2.temp_id
WHERE   t1.assembly_item_id = 8321
```

---

### Note: zil_ibat_resolve_bmi_ai_max_v is a view.

What is wrong with this query? Why is it taking so much time when I query table instead of putting the IDs directly in the inner section? Is there an alternate for this?

### Explain Plan

usedSelectQueryInInnerSection.png
[image]

usedJoin
[image]

enterNumbersInInnerQuery
[image]

Comment: Oracleʹs temporary tables are similar to temporary tables in other relational databases with the **main exception** being that they are ʹstaticallyʹ defined. You create them once per database, not once per stored procedure in the database. They always exist ‐ they will be in the data dictionary as objects, but will always appear empty until your session puts data into them.

Comment: So where are you creating your tables?

Comment: @abhi, you can assume that an ordinary table, not temp table. But still there is the same issue.

And forgot to mention, zil_ibat_resolve_bmi_ai_max_v is a View. updated the question.

Comment: Do you have the necessary tools, privileges to run an [Explain PLAN](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Explain_Plan)?

Comment: I would guess that in the first one `view merge` or `predicate push-down` is used. I agree with @abhi that you have to post execution plans of all three queries. Only then something more specific can be said.

Comment: not much aware of explain plan. However I can see that in my Toad. Graphically...

Comment: Before you run against the query, could you run `dbms_stats.set_table_stats` on the temporary table.

Comment: In TOAD you can put your cursor on the query and press `Ctrl+E`, then you get the Explain plan.

Comment: I updated the question by adding the explain plan for all the 3 queries... Last image is where I ented numbers in inner query and faster...

Answer (score 2):

The second and third query are slow because of the NESTED LOOP join between the view results and the temporary table.  Changing it to a HASH join, perhaps through better optimizer statistics or a `USE_HASH` hint, should speed up the query.

**Problem**

This part at the top of the execution plan:

```
NESTED LOOPS
    zil_ibat_resolve_bmi_ai_max_v
    global_temp_ids
```

is similar to this pseudo-code:

```
for each row of zil_ibat_resolve_bmi_ai_max_v
    search index of global_temp_ids
```

Based on the images the execution plan for the view does not change between queries, that part must be relatively fast.  And the look-up of the temporary table uses a unique index search, that must also be fast.  But it is only fast to do it *once*.  And we can tell from the the `Cardinality 1` that the Oracle optimizer *thinks* it will only execute the inner part of the join once.

NESTED LOOPs are great when joining a small number of rows.  HASH JOINs work much better when joining a large number of rows.

**Solutions**

There are many ways to change the join method, here are the two to try first:

*1. Gather statistics.*  Better optimizer statistics will improve the cardinality estimates, which will usually improve execution plans.  There are many ways to gather stats but usually the default settings are the best.  In this case they can be gathered by running a procedure like this: `exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats('SMART');`  Repeat that for the schemas ZILADMIN and XCBAIRAG.  If the statistics were missing or stale it would also be a good idea to investigate why the default statistics gathering job did not run.

*2. Hint.*  Hints should generally be avoided in production code but they can still at least be helpful to diagnose the problem.  Run the query with the hint `SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(t1 t2) */ ...` and see if that improves things.  If that works you can either keep the hint or consider using some other form of plan management.  For example, a SQL Profile may solve this and other problems in a cleaner way.  Check with other developers or DBAs to find out what types of plan management features are common in your system.